# Is it better to glClear() before drawing to a buffer or after?

Tags: c++, opengl, optimization

I currently have code that does the following:

1. sleep until next frame
2. `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DPETH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);`
3. perform all drawing for the frame
4. flush and display drawing to screen
5. sleep until next frame (again)

My question is: should the clear (2) be moved to happen after step 4?

This order is nice because it's easier to prep a render buffer for rendering conceptually, like putting primer on a canvas, as opposed to cleaning the render buffer up afterwards.  But I'm worried the GPU might get stuck on each clear and delay the drawing commands immediately after it, meaning it should be used when the GPU has nothing to do yet, like right before waiting for the next frame to begin.

Best case scenario:  This order is fine and I'm being paranoid, `glClear()` doesn't delay other opengl drawing commands in any meaningful way.

Worst case scenario:  `glClear()` is best called after a frame is rendered, where there's downtime for it to work since no other opengl commands are queued up yet.

Comment: If you use a skybox which fills every (left) background pixel, it can gain a little bit performance to draw it last. In this case, clearing depth buffer (and stencil) only might be sufficient. (All color pixels are definitely filled in rendering.) However, the `glClear()` still must be done first.

Comment: Found a similar question on Khronos: [Avoid glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT )?](https://community.khronos.org/t/avoid-glclear-gl-color-buffer-bit/65771/2)

Comment: @scheff - it wasn't, edited that line to fix that

Comment: If you have to _sleep until next frame_, doesn't it mean that you don't have to care when to `glClear()`. On the other hand, if CPU has spare time but GPU is ful, then the total time won't change. In any case, you have to clear before rendering and after swapping buffers... (and swapping your code won't change this fact, would it?)

Comment: @scheff - That's true, the frame rate wouldn't be affected, I'm just trying to reduce input latency.  Input happens at the start of each frame, so the sooner I can push a frame out from that moment, the better off the latency is.  So moving the clear out of that zone is tempting, but it's really painful to code it so the clear happens last.  Hopefully it's pointless (the clear is as free before drawing as it is after drawing) and I don't have to do it lol

Comment: I've tested this and it doesn't make a difference, but my GPU is pretty recent.  I need to buy a shitty card for these types of things

Comment: Or, even simpler: write a customer recommendation for a recent graphics card. (This is what we do.) ;-)

Comment: Doing the clear before or after the drawing is ultimately a completely moot point because the code is executed in a loop (doing it last just screws up the first frame, obviously). Putting any CPU-side waits inbetween any of these points will also make almost no difference, as the GPU will work asynchronously anyway.

Comment: @derhass: agreed. Except I think it can have implications on latency.