# OpenGL window artifacts

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I recently started to learn OpenGl using tutorials and books. In most of them I can find a notice like that:

> When an application draws in a single buffer the resulting image might display flickering issues. ... To circumvent these issues, windowing applications apply a double buffer for rendering.

Sounds reasonable, so for that purpose I should use `glfwSwapBuffers(window);` in my render loop.
Unfortunately I still get this artifacts.

But, if I clear **color buffer bit** before swapping, then it works well.

So the question is: Why those artifacts are gone, only after clearing bits. I would be pleased if you help me to figure out why that's happening.

Here's a code snippet of that render loop:

```cpp
// Render loop
// -----------
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
    processInput(window);

    // Rendering commands
    // ------------------
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

Comment: You have to clear the frame buffer before rendering. That's totally usual in OpenGL. If it worked in single buffering without, then you just overpainted what was left from previous rendering. Your tutorial should've teached this. Concerning your exposed code: Maybe, your comments are a bit misleading but this is the proper order or your rendering step: 1. `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` 2. do rendering 3. `glfwSwapBuffers(window);`. Btw. What about depth buffer? Shouldn't it be cleared as well? (Or, do you not yet use depth tests?)

Comment: FYI: [SO: Is it better to glClear() before drawing to a buffer or after?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56607177/7478597) Unfortunately, it isn't answered but there are some comments.

Comment: @Scheff, thanks for your comment! It helped to clarify the picture!

Comment: OpenGL does not automatically clear the buffers for you because it cannot know how you want to use them and if you want to reuse the content of it. So the buffers are always left in the state they were, and it is your responsibility to clean those parts of the buffer that you want to have cleared. On the other hand, this allows you to reuse the contents of a buffer, which can be useful if you want to do some advanced layered rendering effects.

Comment: The artifacts you get from not clearing the buffer are different from the artifacts you get from not using double buffering.